# Deleting a database entry upon button click in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a custom plugin in WordPress. The plugin have the following functionality:
1. Adds entry to database upon filling and submitting the form correctly. 
2. Lists the entries from the database and 
3. Delete entry from the listed items.

I have managed to get the first two tasks done. I have problem with deleting the entry upon clicking delete on the entry.

The entries are listed in the table format with delete button. Clicking on the delete button to delete appropriate entry in the database.

The approach which I have tried; Adding confirm dialog on the submit input and setting the form.action to certain to catch the POST request.

```
this.form.action.value = 'delete';
```

Added the submit button the following code to create the POST request deleteFile.

```
<?php submit_button( __( 'Delete' ), 'secondary', 'deleteFile' ) ?>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the `WP_List_Table`'s method `column_title` to add the delete link to the item. Please check the code below:

```
$actions = array(
            'view'   => sprintf( '<a target="_blank" href="%s%s">View</a>', $upload_location, $item->real_filename ),
            'edit'   => sprintf( '<a id="edit" href="?page=%s&action=%s&file=%s" onclick="javascript: setSaveBtn();">Edit</a>', 'digitalspital-files-edit', 'edit', $item->id ),
            'delete' => sprintf( '<a href=' . $nonced_url . ' data-delete>Delete</a>' ),
        );
```